# Training Model with Keras Backend: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a deep learning model (variational autoencoder, VAE) using keras backend, 
and have followed the guideline to do available at https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-custom-training-loop-59ce779d60fb. The code which I used for defining the loss function, building the vae and training the model is provided below.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
>     (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_10' with dtype float and shape [?,80,176,3]
>        [[{{node input_10}}]]
>        [[add_359/_1299]]
>     (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_10' with dtype float and shape [?,80,176,3]
>        [[{{node input_10}}]]
>   0 successful operations.
>   0 derived errors ignored.

```
def loss_fn(vae_input,vae_output,vae,n_row,n_col,n_chn): 
    vae_loss = klosses.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(vae_input), K.flatten(vae_output))  #this is the reconstruction loss
    vae_loss *= n_row * n_col * n_chn
    vae_loss += vae.losses[0] #adds KL divergence loss   
    return vae_loss

lr_training = 1e-3 
vae_optimizer = Adam(lr=lr_training)

#getting individual sizes of data_set dimensions
n_row = data_set.shape[1]
n_col = data_set.shape[2]
n_channel = data_set.shape[3]
n_datapoints = data_set.shape[0]

#building vae using these dimensions
vae, encoder, generator = build_vae(n_row, n_col, n_chn, n_filters, n_z, beta=1)

#defining vae input and output tensors
vae_input = Input(shape=(data_set.shape[1:])) #equivalent of y_true
vae_output = vae(vae_input) #feed value here... #equivalent of y_pred

#defining loss tensor and updates operation
vae_loss = loss_fn(vae_input,vae_output,vae,n_row,n_col,n_chn)
updates_op = vae_optimizer.get_updates(loss=vae_loss, params = vae.trainable_weights)

train = K.function(inputs=[vae_input], outputs=[vae_loss], updates=updates_op)

# training
n_train = n_datapoints
losses = {'vae': []}

for ie in range(n_epochs):
    print('\nepoch: %d' % (ie + 1))
    idx_randperm = np.random.permutation(n_train) #shuffles sequence of numbers within train range.
    n_batches = n_train // batch_size #how many batches per epoch.
    progbar = generic_utils.Progbar(n_batches * batch_size, stateful_metrics=['Total loss'])
    for batch_count in range(n_batches): #for each batch size
        sess = K.get_session()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())     
        idx_real_batch = idx_randperm[range(batch_count* batch_size, batch_count * batch_size + batch_size)]
        data_real_batch = data_set[idx_real_batch]
        vae_loss_train = train([K.constant(data_real_batch)])
        losses['vae'].append(vae_loss_train_val[0])
        # update progress bar
        progbar.add(batch_size, values=[('Total loss', losses['vae'][-1])])
        print ('here!')
        sess.close()
```

To summarize, I am using **Input(shape=(data_set.shape[1:]))** as my **vae input** and feeding the **training function's input** with **K.constant(data_real_batch)**, where data_real_batch is a numpy multidimensional array.

Additionally, I am using **TensorFlow version 1.14.0** and **Keras version 2.3.1.**

Would appreciate any help and thoughts on overcoming this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think culprit is here:

`vae_input = Input(shape=(data_set.shape[1:]))`

which means you pass input shape as tuple where first item is list of shape and correct way is to just pass tuple (or list) of values:

`vae_input = Input(shape=data_set.shape[1:])`

But I will not put my hand in the fire for that ...
Also not sure about this line:

```
data_real_batch = data_set[idx_real_batch]
```

And maybe you need to add batch dimension by something like this (and also add: import numpy as np) - if input shape without batch is 80,176,3, than data_real_batch needs to have shape 1,80,176,3:

```
data_real_batch = data_set[idx_real_batch]
data_real_batch = np.expand_dims(data_real_batch, axis=0)
```

Probably another problem is in training loop:

```
sess = K.get_session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  
sess.close()
```

You can try to also to remove those lines. In your case training is done by this line below and there is probably no need of those lines above:

```
vae_loss_train = train([K.constant(data_real_batch)])
```

Comment: Thanks @oktogen. I made this change, but it does not make a difference to the error; I am still getting the invalid argument and must feed placeholder issue

Comment: In the link from medium he does not use sess = K.get_session() and his code working on my pc without problems. Tensoflow session need to pass inputs as feed_dict if I remember correctly btw.